# Using RF scanners in vb 2010

Tags: vb.net

Let me start off by saying I am new to vb and as far as scripting goes, i've only ever really used matlab.

Anyway, I am writing a script in vb2010 that will allow for me to read and write from mysql. everything is in test mode. I was able to get it to read and write, but for the next phase of this endeavor I want the script to be able to read from mysql after reading a barcoded number from a scanner. Once it can do that, I feel confident that I can finish the code.

I don't even know where to begin as far as the rf scanner scripting is concerned.

Here is what I have already:

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports System.Data


Public Class TEST

    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection
    Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand
    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
    Dim par As MySqlParameter
    Dim result As String


    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        TextBox4.Text = Now.ToString()

        'Dim str As String
        'Dim num As Integer
        'str = ComboBox1.Text
        'num = CInt(str)
        conn = New MySqlConnection
        conn.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=test;Uid=root;Pwd=****;"

        Try
            conn.Open()
            MessageBox.Show("Connection Opened Successfully")
            myCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO this (workorderno, Datein, operator) values ('" & TextBox1.Text & "', '" & TextBox2.Text & "', '" & combobox1.Text & "')"
            myCommand.Connection = conn
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()        
            conn.Close()
        Catch myerror As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show("Error Connecting to Database: " & myerror.Message)
        Finally
            conn.Dispose()
        End Try

        Try
            conn.Open()
            MessageBox.Show("Connection established")         
            myCommand = New MySqlCommand("Select number From this Where workorderno = @textbox1.text", conn)
            par = New MySqlParameter
            par.ParameterName = "textbox1.text"
            par.Value = TextBox1.Text
            myCommand.Parameters.Add(par)
            reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader()
            If reader.Read() Then
                result = reader.GetString(0)
            End If
            ''//output to textbox
            TextBox3.Text = result

            conn.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
        Finally
            conn.Dispose()
        End Try


    End Sub
```

Comment: We do not have enough information to even try to make a guess, to start with what model of RF Scanner are you going to use.

Comment: a simple Motorola LS2208-SR20001R-UR Barcode Scanner is what i have in mind. Please let me know if there is anymore relevant information required

Comment: Have you already installed the driver software?

Comment: I have not. I can do that though if that is the next step in this process

Comment: What I would do is install the software, write a small test application to make sure that you can receive the data, then once you get to that point integrate into your application.

Answer (score 0):

Saying your scanner communicates with your computer with serial interface, which your program can read it through COM port, you can first add in the `SerialPort` to your project, enter the `Port Name`, which I guess you can find it in the Device Manager. Then you can start open the port, add the `SerialPortDataDidReceived` function from the `SerialPort` actions.

For reference, this video from youtube should help you out a bit :]

[Visual Basic Serial COM Port Tutorial (Visual Studio 2010)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wsMMHaSvvRU)

You should find some tutorials with the keyword `Serial Port` hope this can help! =]